# Ошибка запуска Laravel Sail в терминале

Tags: laravel, docker, консоль, macos, zsh

Устанавливаю по инструкции с офф сайта Laravel, установил Docker
перешел в папку проекта
cd example

и запускаю

```
./vendor/bin/sail up
```

и выходит ошибка `zsh: no such file or directory: ./vendor/bin/sail`

в какую сторону думать?

[image: ошибка в терминале]

Comment: Зависимости установили?